# How to persiste or save the JavaFX UI state?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

This has been asked here:
[How to persist JavaFX GUI State?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355755/how-to-persist-javafx-gui-state)
And has the tag javafx-2. But no answers.

Gonna ask again and put in more tags.

I'm looking for something like what was done in  **JSR 296: Swing Application Framework** where the demo application remembers it's window size, location etc. E.g if the user maximized the window, and then closes, opens the program again, the window is maximized.

Comment: Here is a simple example of [using a `Properties` file to persist the Swing frame size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7778332/418556).

Comment: Yeah I'm doing that actually. I have this combobox that I want it to persist it's state: [screenshot](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/75921/10032589/81fdfbc6-61b6-11e5-9eb7-df72f8d3f49c.png). I'm using java.util.Properties for this

Comment: *"I have this combobox that I want it to persist it's state:"*  So.. go for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store basic information using the [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API.

Depending on the operating system, the preferences are saved in different places (for example in Windows, they are stored in the registry file).

Typical use goes like this:

- To store a value:

  ```
  Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MyClass.class);
  prefs.putBoolean("isWindowMaximized", true);
  ```
- To get a value:

  ```
  Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MyClass.class);
  boolean value = prefs.getBoolean("isWindowMaximized", false);
  ```

You will find more information about this API in this [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/).

Comment: Is it a good thing that the application messes around with the registry?
But I'll check it out, hopefully it's can be configured to save into a properties file instead. Otherwise I guess it's a bit of an improvement over plain java.util.Properties

Comment: but not like Swing Application Framework. where the ui state persistence is done automatically